# PHP: create string with values separated by comma BUT without comma at the end of string

Tags: php, string, foreach

I am using the following PHP snippet to echo data to an HTML page. 
This works fine so far and returns results like the following example: 
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5,

How can I prevent it from also adding a comma at the end of the string while keeping the commas between the single values ?

**My PHP:**

```
<?php foreach ($files->tags->fileTag as $tag) { echo $tag . ", "; } ?>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
$files->tags->fileTag
```

is an array, then you can use

```
$str = implode(', ', $files->tags->fileTag);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It turned out this is the best solution for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
implode(", ", $files->tags->fileTag);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is keep a counter and check for every record the index compared with the total item tags.

```
<?php 
$total = count($files->tags->fileTag);
foreach ($files->tags->fileTag as $index =>  $tag) { 
   if($index != $total - 1){
        echo $tag.',';
     } else{
        echo $tag;
     }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks very good too. I forgot to mention that my input is an xml string so the $index wouldnt work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo implode(",",$files->tag->fileTag);
?>
```

Comment: feel free to validate answer then

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using an array to iterate through, how about instead of using a foreach loop, you use a regular for loop and put an if statement at the end to check if it's reached the length of the loop and echo $tag on it's own?

Pseudocode off the top of my head:

```
for($i = 0, $i < $files.length, $i++){
    if ($i < $files.length){
        echo $tag . ", ";
    } else {
        echo $tag;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps x

Edit: The implode answers defo seem better than this, I'd probably go for those x